# How to put several inputfield in a same row in manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, inputfield

```
   Manipulate[
    Module[{stot, s, Usite, H, Ps, Pw, deltap, Cp, V, Q, m, E},
  E = m*enthalpie*hour/effi;
  m = 60*Q*rho;
  Q = V*A;
  V = Cd*K*deltap^0.5;
  deltap = Ps + Pw;
  Ps = 0.00598*(rho0 - rhoi)*g*H*Ct;
  Pw = 0.0129*Cp*rho*Usite^2/2;
  Usite = stot*umet*(D/gamma)^alpha;
  stot = f*s/ftot;
  s = 0.5*((s1 + s2)*cos[phi]^2 + (s1 - s2)*cos[phi] + (s3 + s4)*
   sin[phi]^2 + (s3 - s4)*sin[phi]);
 Cp = 0.3*cos[phi]^0.25 + 0.9*cos[phi]^0.75;
 H = Which[csb == 1, Hbuilding, csb == 2, 0, csb == 3, 
0.5*Hbuilding - 3, csb == 4, Hbuilding*0.5]; E], 
Item["Choose Crack Area Type", Alignment -> Left], Delimiter,
 Control[{{csb, 1, ""}, {1 -> "Roof", 2 -> "Wall", 3 -> "Door", 
4 -> "Slab"}, SetterBar}], Delimiter, 
  Item["Observation Parameters", 
  Alignment -> 
   Left], Delimiter, {phi}, {s1}, {s2}, {s3}, {s4}, {f}, {umet}, {D}, \
{alpha}, {gamma}, {rho}, {Ct}, {g}, {effi}, {enthalpie}, {ftot}, \
{rho0}, {rhoi}, {K}, {Cd}, {hour}, Delimiter, 
 Item["Building Geometry", Alignment -> Left], Delimiter,
 Row[{Control[{{A, 150, Row[{"Crack Area"}]}, 0, 50, 2, 
 Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small}], 
 Control[{{Hbuilding, 80, Row[{"Building Height"}]}, 0, 50, 2, 
 Appearance -> "Labeled", Paneled -> True, 
 ContinuousAction -> True, ImageSize -> Small}]}], 
 AppearanceElements -> All]
```

My question is that, how can I put several inputfield in a same row here in manipulate? And how to make the output result is a numeric value instead of a symbolic expression. Thx a lot.

Comment: Row[{Control[input1...], Control[input2], ...  }] -- the same way you put the "crack area" and "building height" into a single row.

Answer (score 2):

To flesh out the comment, you need to add `Control` to each of the variables, and a Row[ ] to get them in a row.

```
Row[{Control[{phi}], Control[{s1}], Control[{s2}]}]
```

will put your first three in a single row.

As a simple example:

```
Manipulate[phi*s1*s2, 
 Row[{Control[{phi}], Control[{s1}], Control[{s2}]}]]
```

Notice that the answer contains Nulls until you have entered values for all the variables. Once entered, the calculation is done automatically. You can also add default values:

```
Row[{Control[{phi, 1}], Control[{s1, 2}], Control[{s2, 3}]}]
```

so now phi is 1, s1 is 2, etc, until you change them.